# __repr__ method appears can't be invoked automatically for Exception class

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was told that if an obj's `__str__` method isn't created but `__repr__` is created then printing the obj will invoke `__repr__`. That appears to be true for normal class, but when I try it on Exception's subclass, it is weird that `__repr__` doesn't get invoked, could anyone explain why?

Here's an example

```
class BoringError(Exception):
  def __init__(self):
    self.purpose = "Demonstration"
    self.boringLevel = 10
  def __repr__(self):
    return "I'm a message for developer"

 try: 
   if 1 != 2:
    raise BoringError 
 except BoringError as e:
   print(e.boringLevel)
   print(e)

class Tree:
  def __repr__(self):
    return "I love water"

AVL = Tree()
print(AVL)
```

This program produces the following result

```
10

I love water
```

Instead of

```
10
I'm a message for developer
I love water
```

Comment: `e.__str__` *is* defined, though; it just resolves to `Exception.__str__`, not `BoringError.__str__`.

Comment: I see, so it's because parent class's method is invoked

Comment: `print(e)` calls `print(e.__str__())` not `print(e.__repr__())`

Answer (score 4):

`__repr__` is only invoked if `e.__str__` resolves to `object.__str__`, which is basically defined like

```
def __str__(self):
    return self.__repr__()
```

In your case, `object.__str__` is never invoked, because `e.__str__` resolves to `Exception.__str__`, which does *not* invoke any definition of `__repr__`. Compare:

```
>>> e = Exception("hi")
>>> print(e)
hi
>>> str(e)
'hi'
>>> repr(e)
"Exception('hi')"
```

`Tree.__str__` is not defined, so `AVL.__str__` *does* resolve to `object.__str__`, hence `Tree.__repr__` gets called.

Answer (score 3):

When an exception is printed `__str__` is called not `__repr__`. See the [handling exception documentation](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/errors.html#handling-exceptions):

> The except clause may specify a variable after the exception name. The variable is bound to an exception instance with the arguments stored in `instance.args`. **For convenience, the exception instance defines `__str__()` so the arguments can be printed directly without having to reference `.args`**. One may also instantiate an exception first before raising it and add any attributes to it as desired.

Consider the following:

```
try:
    raise NameError('HiThere')
except NameError as e:
    print(e)
```

When `print(e)` is called, the instance `e` has a `__str__` method that returns the arguments it was created with, in this case the string `'HiThere'`.

That's how you can use `print(e)` instead of explicitely using `print(e.args)`.

In your case, there are no arguments passed to `BoringError`, therefore `print(e)` prints an empty string.

Overriding the `__str__` method with:

```
 def __str__(self):
     return "I'm a message for developer"
```

gives the expected result.

Comment: Can u explain the documentation in more simple language? It's explanation is a bit too technical